# How to batch select and move multiple artboards in Sketch

Tags: batch-processing, sketch-app, artboard, selections

I have a problem moving the selected artboards: only the first one in the batch moves while the selection had shown all N artboards selected (first and last artboards having the white small squares around them after I click and drag the left key on my mouse).

I need this feature when I realize that I left out something I meant to go in the middle AFTER having drawn the end screens and now there is no room for them. To preserve the logical order of the artboards I prefer to order them and currently have to do it manually dragging each and every artboard one by one to give the forgotten artboards some room.

I am pretty new to Sketch and may just have as well missed this function, please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Use the layers panel

I find the easiest way to accurately select multiple artboards is the layers panel. Collapse the artboard groups (if your list is too long), then command-click each title you're after.

[image: Artboards selected in the layers panel]

## Three ways to move

1. **Click and drag the title of any selected artboard in the workspace.** Don't miss or you'll lose your selection! (>_<)
2. **Use the cursor keys** (with shift for bigger jumps). Tedious, but foolproof.
3. **Enter values in the x/y position fields.** Accurate, but often requires a guess.

[image: Empty x/y position fields]

^ As you can see above, if your artboards don't share a common dimension, the x/y positions will be blank. Entering a value will align them all to that position. This can be a very handy way to organize your file.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to move multiple artboards at once, you'll have to do a batch select by Shift-Clicking the artboards' titles you want to move, and then drag all of them around by Click-Dragging a title.

You cant move multiple artboards at once by Drag-Selecting them.

Comment: while shift-selecting the title did work the way I expected, drag-selecting didn't. Only the artboard that has the mouse pointer over it moves. Am I doing it wrong? I hold the left mouse key and drag the pointer over the needed artboards.

Comment: I did a quick screencast on how to do it: http://recordit.co/c6VyNhlTw2
1. Select Artboard titles you want to move while holding shift
2. Click and drag on any title you've just selected.

Answer (score 0):

I often have problems with the auto-selection feature grabbing a layer and moving the layer instead of the artboard. Select the artboards you want to move in the layers panel, then hold Option + Command to keep Sketch from changing or releasing your selection. Drag (from anywhere) to your heart's content.

http://www.sketchapp.com/support/documentation/03-layer-basics/3-moving-layers.html

Comment: Welcome to the site, paul! If you have any questions about how things work, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

After updating to Sketch Version 3.4. You now need to hold down '**command + option**' to drag and move an artboard around the canvas.

Comment: Hi Sacha, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

This Sketch plugin selects the artboards of all selected layers:

https://github.com/nefaurk/select-parent-artboards

This can be used for moving artboards on the canvas, or reordering them on the left layers panel.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that this plugin works for this purpose: https://github.com/romannurik/Sketch-ArtboardTricks

You drag-select artboards on the canvas, then press ctrl + cmd + A and it changes the selection from layers to the artboards instead.

Answer (score -1):

http://sketchhunt.com/2016/08/23/select-parent-artboards-sketch-plugin/

Easy peasy lemon squeezy, I got you boss.

Comment: We're looking for complete answers, not one-liners, can you at least include the main info behind the link? Link rot is a big issue, and if the website goes down your answer becomes useless to the community. If you have any more questions check the [help] or pop into the chat. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!